# Example of two prime ideals whose sum is proper but not prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can someone give me an example of two prime ideals whose sum is proper, but not prime?

Or, on the other hand, prove that the sum of two prime ideals is either prime or the whole ring?

Comment: Consider $C[x,y]$ with $(y-x^2)$ which is irreducible variety. Hence prime. and another variety $(y)$ which is the line and hence prime. The intersection $(y-x^2)+(y)=(y,x^2)$ which is clearly not prime by taking $x\cdot x\in (y,x^2)$

Comment: $(x)+(x\!+\!4) = (x,x\!+\!4) = (x,4)\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\ \ $

Comment: Geometrically it is obviously possible that two irreducible curves meet at two or more points (or at only one point, but not transversal). Algebraically this turns into a an example of prime ideals with a proper sum not being prime.

Comment: Shall we have some more answers in the comments, then? I'm not quite sure there are enough yet...